# Upload file attachments to a ServiceNow record via REST API

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, servicenow

I access the `ServiceNow REST API` from a `.net WinForms/C#` application for creating and updating records such as Incidents, Tasks, etc.

I need the functionality to upload file attachments to the records, but I don't see this function anywhere within the REST API documentation on ServiceNow Wiki. Only `SOAP` based approaches are given as solutions to uploading file attachments. Can this be done at all, through the REST API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently (up to Fuji Release of ServiceNow) there is not a REST API for interacting with Attachments in ServiceNow.

Check out the following blog post (link below) which walks through how to use the ServiceNow JSONV2 API to create attachments in ServiceNow using JSON instead of SOAP/XML.

http://www.john-james-andersen.com/blog/service-now/generate-attachments-in-servicenow-via-rest.html